# jasper excel report export green mark coming

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am using jasper stuido 6 to generated excel report.
After generating report I am getting green mark on cell wherever is number is coming as shown below image

[image: Screenshot of generated report]

same green mark is not coming from text value only.

I tried to set the below jasper property

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
```

and used below code

```
<jr:column width="50" uuid="d3d82c7c-1121-474f-b0f3-00e80cda4489">
    <jr:detailCell height="20">
        <textField>
            <reportElement style="WhiteBackColor" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="20" uuid="1b71e76d-8111-43ee-9cfb-9070ffcf1f6d">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{zeitQuartal}.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Calibri" size="11" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[Double.parseDouble($F{zeitQuartal})]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </jr:detailCell>
</jr:column>
```

Then green mark disapper from the generated excel report
but if any text like come in between number that is disappearing

Comment: using property <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>

Comment: <textField>
        <reportElement style="WhiteBackColor" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="20" uuid="1b71e76d-8111-43ee-9cfb-9070ffcf1f6d">
         <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{zeitQuartal}.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")]]></printWhenExpression>
        </reportElement>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
         <font fontName="Calibri" size="11" isBold="true"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[Double.parseDouble($F{zeitQuartal})]]></textFieldExpression>
       </textField>